# SSIS: Package password error when building

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

We have several hundred SSIS packages in a Visual Studio Integration Services project.  When this was originally set up it was configured to encrypt sensitive data in the packages with the user key.  This caused some issues for us when the project file was checked out and we had conflicts because, of course, our different developer user keys were different.

We just attempted to change to sensitive data with password.  To do that we had to update the project property and then we had to do it for every package manually (I tried looping using dtutil.exe but for some reason it did not work). To build my project I had to open every single package, change the password, and then build the project.  After a few hours of this and getting every package updated and saved I was able to build and deploy my packages.

After that I did a commit/push to source control (Azure Git) and when my co-worker did a pull and opened the project they are now unable to build with the same error.  If he puts the password in and checks everything in and I pull it back down, I get the error again.

The package and project passwords match, I can build, but when it's pulled down we get the error.

The error is:
"Project consistency check failed. The following inconsistencies were detected:
[package Name] has a different password than the project"

Comment: Is the project using Project deployment model or Package deployment model? I haven't had any problems with passwords, all my projects are using the Package deployment model

Comment: You may need to set the package protection at the project level and check in the project or solution files in addition to the SSIS package files. And then make sure everyone does a "Get Latest" before opening the project/solution files again.

Comment: @Gigga - the project is using Project Deployment.

Comment: @digital.aaron - I set the package protection at project level first and then all of the packages.  After building I checked it ALL in and the other developers have pulled that all down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue but I was not able to figure out exactly what is occurring. I basically changed my protection level to DontSaveSensitive and made sure all of my passwords and sensitive information were parameterized and passed in using SSIS environment variables.

So after making sure all sensitive data was not saved in the packages I changed the project protection level and the protection level of every package. I changed the packages using this code:

```
for %f IN (*.dtsx) DO dtutil.exe /file %f /encrypt file;%f;0 /quiet
```

This changed the setting for the packages but I still received the error when building. I had to open each package, change the protection level property to any other value then back to DontSaveSensitive and then build.  Once I did that the items fell out of the error message. After doing that manually for 650+ packages I was able to build.  The most important resolution was that once I did a push and my co-worker pulled the changes down, they did not have to edit each package.  When I was using encrypt sensitive with password we could not stop it from requiring a change and build on every package.

This is still a bit of a mystery, why dtutil.exe would not just change them without needing to re-build is very frustrating.  But this work around ultimately got us past the problem and parameterizing was probably the best practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, my problem was that I was missing to introduce the password in the properties of every package (not only in the project), after doing that I have been able to rebuild the project.

[image]